# How can I signal/force the parent shell to change directory?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command, subshell

I have this command called `reclone`, and this is my script:

```
. load

sudo -v

extract

sudo rm -rf /$organization/$repository

cd /$organization

git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:$organization/$repository

cd /
```

Basically, I call my other scripts to extract some data related to the **PWD** and find out the name of the org and repo, delete the repo, and use `git clone` to clone it again.

It works fine. The problem is that since I call the `reclone` command in the `/some-org/some-repo` directory, and inside I remove that directory, the `cd /` at the end does not work.

This means when the `reclone` is completed, the user is still at the `/some-org/some-repo` which has an invalid handle, and all future commands would show errors.

How can I tell the parent shell from within my custom command to change the directory? Is there a way for this at all?